# Refer to objects dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection

Say I have 2 objects `ObjA` and `ObjB`. Assuming that they are from the same class with a method called `CommonMethod()`, I am looking for a method to do something like this:

```
void CallObjectMethod(string name)
{
    // where name could be 'A' or 'B'
    (Obj + name).CommonMethod();
}
```

instead of doing the long way:

```
void CallObjectMethod(string name)
{
    if(name == 'A')
        objA.CommonMethod();
    else if(name == 'B')
        objB.CommonMethod();
}
```

I understand this probably can be done through reflection, but not quite sure how to achieve this.

Comment: I think you should look at creating an interface for "CommonMethod". Then make objA and objB implement that interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both `ObjA` and `ObjB` are of class `SomeClass` and are fields (member variables) of `this`, you can use the following. If the caller supplies the wrong suffix (e.g. not "A" and not "B") the method will throw an exception, of course.

```
class Example
{
    private SomeClass ObjA;
    private SomeClass ObjB;

    void CallObjectMethod(string suffix)
    {
        string name = "Obj" + suffix;
        var fieldInfo = this.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (fieldInfo == null || (fieldInfo.FieldType != typeof(SomeClass)) throw ArgumentException(nameof(suffix));
        SomeClass obj = fieldInfo.GetValue(this) as SomeClass;
        obj.CommonMethod();
    }
}
```

Note: While this solution does exactly what you ask, I don't recommend it. You would normally not want your implementation to depend on private field names being passed in a string. You are probably better off using a dictionary, maybe like this:

```
class Example
{
    Dictionary<string, SomeClass> _objects = new Dictionary<string, SomeClass>();

    public SomeClass()
    {
        _objects["A"] = new SomeClass();
        _objects["B"] = new SomeClass();
    }

    void CallObjectMethod(string key)
    {
        _objects[key].CommonMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: This (the first option) actually will only work for the instances that are (private) fields of this class. If an instance with the right name exits elsewhere it will not be found.

Comment: Hi Johan, yes, I did state that in the assumptions. Under different assumptions the example could be made to work with minor changes, so hopefully this will get the OP the direction he needs.

Answer (score 6):

You should use a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) of the Types `<string, Obj>` and then in the method do:

```
void CallObjectMethod(string name)
{
   Obj ObjFromDictionary = MyDictionary[name];
   ObjFromDictionary.CommonMethod();
}
```

you can of course call that directly without creating a temporary `Obj ObjFromDictionary`...

and you should validate that string parameter first...